# How to fix double-counting of FB app installs when using a mmp (adjust)?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, analytics, tracking

We use both facebook sdk and adjust sdk (facebook mobile measurement partner). When running Ad campaigns on facebook, both send to facebook analytics an 'install' event resulting that facebook shows double as much installs (for every user 2 installs). I haven't found a way to remove the 'install' event for either of the them and keeping at the same time all other event tracking intact. What is the technical solution here to just get one event per user to facebook analytics?

Comment: I assume Adjust would know

Comment: thanks @WizKid. We have been trying to figure it out with Adjust with no luck so far. One thing I noticed: FB Analytics shows for iOS an infobox "mmp detected, duplicates removed" whereas for Android app no such box is present. The implementation on our side should be same. What could be the reason android doesn't recognise the mmp? screenshots here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4iyloyfb32lg3zk/AADU8VsfhGxJAJODwxDiAD6Fa?dl=0